# how printf do for printf("%c",0);

Tags: c

i need for a school projet to remake printf.

i almost finish it but i got a problem in case :

```
          printf("%c", 0);
```

printf print "^@"
that is the representation of \x00 or NULL

i try to print it with write(1, c, 1); where c = 0;

but it show me nothing.

```
  ➜  printf3 sh test.sh |cat -e
     ft_printf =$
     printf    =^@$
     $
```

that is the result of printf with cat -e.

i try to make a stupid putstr that take special care of this type of situation :

```
    void    ft_putstr(char *str)
    {
        char c;

        c = 0;
        if (*str == 0)
            write(1, &c, 1);
        else
            while (*str)
        write(1, str++, 1);
    }
```

how could i printf this special signe that is "^@" = 0 = \x00 = NULL

can someone please help me with this issue ? 
thanks you

Comment: You should print the NUL character, ASCII 0. That the terminal will hickup is not your problem - the programmer using your `printf` should not print the null character.

Comment: _"but it show me nothing"_ No, of course not. Nul is a non-printable character.

Comment: If you want to escape the nul character by showing `^@`, then write these two characters, e.g. `write(1,'^',1`);write(1,'@',1);`

Comment: It is further the task of the terminal to show a non-printbale null character as `^@`.

Comment: ... which it does not do by default, regardless of whether it is `printf` or your `ft_printf` that emits a nul character.  In other words, I think you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Hmmm interesting , but I have to write a character that is not visible if I don't do cat-e